# CiviCRM 5.9 upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I just finished the upgrade, and I'm getting an error list at the top of some panels consisting of a series of identical messages:

Notice: Undefined index: name in CRM_Core_SelectValues::quicksearchOptions() (line 1157 of /opt/bitnami/apps/civicrm/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/SelectValues.php).

The panels appear to function normally, but it's rather disconcerting.  These only seem to appear on the first open of the panel.

I didn't notice any error messages or weirdness doing the upgrade.  I did the db upgrade in drush.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like one of your customfield extending 'Contact', 'Individual', 'Organization', 'Household' has missing machine name. The best way to check would be to run below sql query to check if there is any result

```
SELECT id, name, label FROM civicrm_custom_field WHERE (name = '' OR name IS NULL)
```

If you found any rows than run below query to update the name with label

```
UPDATE civicrm_custom_field set name = label WHERE (name = '' OR name IS NULL);
```

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: So there are 3 customfields with NULL name

Comment: Pradeep, yes, I have about 50 of those, but they aren't fields that I added or did anything with, afaik. (|  7 | NULL | Constituent Type                  |)

Comment: Updated my answer to include the fix

Comment: thanks Pradeep, that's the script i was about to write.

Comment: Cheers, Can you please mark this as answered if my solution worked for you so that it will be helpful for others if they face similar problem

Answer (score 3):

If the concern is that it is 'disconcerting' then for a live site it would be normal to turn Drupal "Errors and Warnings" off via admin/config/development/logging

Comment: It's a bit more than that.  It implies to me that something went wrong in the upgrade process.  I wasn't able to find anyone else having the problem, so I'm wondering if anyone has thoughts on the cause.